# How do I install SASS with Mean.io?

Tags: css, sass, mean.io

I have a basic MEAN.io setup. What's confusing me is the package structure. I'd like to use `.scss` files and compile SASS into `.css` files in the final version, but I'm not 100% sure how this works, as I'm just trying to learn.

I've already read the documentation provided by the MEAN.io team, regarding how I can make css files 'global', but I still am not sure how to preprocess `.scss` files.

I haven't tried much, as I'm not really sure what to do. MEAN.io seems to use Gulp by default. I never received a prompt asking me if I prefered Gulp or Grunt (as is shown in MEAN.io's blog).

Any help or examples would be very helpful. I've looked on Google, but most of the stuff I found was MEAN.js stuff. :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To process `.scss` files you can pretty much copy the less configuration.

1. Install gulp sass

   `npm install gulp-sass --save-dev`
2. Update gulp/development.js

   `paths = {
       ...
       sass: [
           'packages/**/*.scss', 
           '!packages/**/node_modules/**',
           '!packages/**/assets/**/lib/**'],
       ...
   };`
3. Create a gulp task to run sass

   `gulp.task('sass', function() {
       return gulp.src(paths.sass)
       .pipe(plugins.sass().on('error', plugins.sass.logError))
       .pipe(gulp.dest('./packages'));
   });`
4. At this point you should be able to run `gulp sass` and it should work but in order for it to run and watch files when you run `gulp` see the next two steps.
5. Add gulp task to defaultTasks (you can remove less if you desire)

   `var defaultTasks = ['coffee','clean', 'less', 'sass', 'csslint', 'devServe', 'watch'];`
6. Add a watch task

   `gulp.task('watch', function () {
     ...
     gulp.watch(paths.sass, ['sass']);
   });`